# How to access POST data on node.js passport authentication?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to access POST parameters after submitting a login form with passport. My form is as follows:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="username">
    <input name="password">
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The (working) express route/callback:

```
app.post(
    '/login', 
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/login', 
        failureFlash: true, 
        badRequestMessage: 'Please enter your account credentials to login.'
    }), 
    function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.param('remember'));
        if(req.isAuthenticated(req, res)) {
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
        } else {
            var errors = req.flash('error');
            if(errors) {
                assign['errors'] = errors;
            }
            res.render('login.html', {errors: errors});
        }
    }
);
```

Login works fine, everything cool. BUT: `req.param('remember')` is always `undefined`. When I remove the passport.authenticate() part, check the checkbox in my form and submit the form console correctly logs `1`.

So how can I access the POST parameters when I'm also using passport.authenticate()?

Comment: Your code seems working to me, try upgrading your express and passport libraries ! I've tested it.

Comment: Ahh, I had another `/login` route a bit higher in my code. Now req.param('remember') works fine but I still can't access the username and password fields within that route. Both the username and the password is undefined when I try to access req.param('username') or req.param('password'). Is it possible that passport deletes the parameters after checking them?

Comment: nope, the parameters are passed untouched ... debug your whole ```req``` variable : ```console.log(req)```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used passport so far but here are two things that might cause your problem

**1. Your form doesn't have an `action` attribute**

Therefore the form doesn't know where to send the data. Try the following

```
<form method="post" action="/login">
  <input name="username">
  <input name="password">
  <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**2. POST variables in express are attached to the `req.body` object**

So instead of

```
console.log(req.param('remember'));
```

use

```
console.log(req.body.username);
```

Make sure you have the [bodyParser](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html) in your express config.

`req.param` is used when you want to access dynamic routes

```
app.get('/login/:user', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.user)
})

// GET /login/john => 'john'
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the action attribute in my example here. In my template it exists of course ;)

Comment: Is configuring the express bodyParser still required?